# Any Dream Journal/Diary software?

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, deb, application-finder

I remember reading about an open-sourced company that developed dream journal software, I think I remember downloading it after i had upgraded to 12.04. Does anyone know if anything exists today, for recording, storing, and analyzing dreams on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

I found these using `apt-cache search`:

```
almanah - Application to ease management of a personal diary
lifeograph - Private digital diary
rednotebook - daily journal with calendar, templates and keyword searching
robojournal - cross-platform journal/diary tool
robojournal-doc - cross-platform journal/diary tool - documentation
```

I also found this:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/dreamdiary/